# What is this Continuous-Space Discrete-Time Markov Chain?

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

So, I was doing my Sunday tinkering and I came across this continuous-space, discrete-time Markov Chain:

1. $X_0 \in (0,1)$, $k \in (0,1)$
2. Update rule:

- With probability $p$, $X_{t+1} = k+(1-k)X_t$
- With probability $1-p$, $X_{t+1} = X_t(1-k)$

I'm interested in learning what this Markov chain is and what its steady-state distribution is, from simulation - I'm fairly convinced its a Beta distribution, as always, proof is preferable!

Comment: Just to be clear, both $k$ and $p$ are fixed?

Comment: @MishaLavrov Yep!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mostly understand what's going on when $k \ge \frac12$.

For a nice special case, let $k = \frac23$ and $p = \frac12$. Then our update rule is that $X_{t+1}$ first multiplies $X_t$ by $\frac13$, and then flips a coin to decide whether to add $\frac23$ or not. If we write $X_t$ as $0.x_1x_2x_3x_4\dots$ in ternary, then $X_{t+1}$ is equally likely to be either $0.0x_1x_2x_3x_4\dots$ or $0.2x_1x_2x_3x_4\dots$ in ternary.

As a result, the limiting distribution is to choose a random number in $[0,1]$ via its ternary representation, putting a $0$ or $2$ in each ternary digit with equal probability. This has a name: it's the [Cantor distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution). The Cantor distribution is, informally, a uniform distribution on the [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set). It is a singular distribution, not even a little discrete (every point has probability $0$) nor even a little continuous (its support has measure $0$).

If we keep $p$ the same, but vary $p$, then as long as $p$ is not either $0$ or $1$, we get a different distribution on the Cantor set, with similar properties.

For other values of $k$ such that $k>\frac12$, we get something similar happening on a Cantor set with different proportions. The update rule of the Markov chain guarantees that $X_1 \in [0,1-k] \cup [k,1]$. Therefore $X_2 \in [0,(1-k)^2] \cup [k(1-k),1-k] \cup [k,k+(1-k)^2] \cup [k+k(1-k),1]$. For $X_t$, we get a similar support of $2^t$ intervals of total length $(2(1-k))^t$.

---

Looking at $k =\frac12$ is trickier, but the answer turns out to be similar. In this case, $X_{t+1}$ is $\frac12 + \frac12X_t$ with probability $p$ and $\frac12X_t$ otherwise. Written in binary, we shift $X_t$ over and put $1$ (with probability $p$) or $0$ (with probability $1-p$) in the first position. This leads to a random real number whose binary digits are chosen from a Bernoulli distribution, and people have thought about this a lot; see, for example, [this question on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1885633/distribution-of-a-random-real-with-i-i-d-bernoullip-binary-digits?noredirect=1&lq=1).

If $p = \frac12$, then this is just the uniform distribution. If $p \ne \frac12$, it is once again purely singular. Suppose, for example, $p = \frac23$. Then we expect that around $\frac23$ of the first $t$ binary digits of $X_t$ are $1$, and around $\frac13$ are $0$, and in the limiting distribution, we expect that this is almost true for almost all $t$. Let $X$ have that limiting distribution. Then with probability $1$, there is a number $N$ such that for all $t \ge N$, at least $0.66t$ of the first $t$ binary digits are $1$. But the set of real numbers in $[0,1]$ with this property has measure $0$.

---

When $k<\frac12$, the intervals $[0,1-k]$ and $[k,1]$ overlap, and the description becomes messy. I do not know what's going on here and I don't know if it's still purely singular. I'm pretty sure that it's not a Beta distribution, because when I looked at a special case, there were no parameters of the Beta distribution that led to the PDF being a fixed point of the update rule.

Comment: Fantastic, did not appear to see the Cantor set! Its a shame that k < 1/2 doesn't appear to have an easy answer.

Comment: Thinking about this some more, aren't we defining a Lebesgue integral here? Most of my simulations are in the low-k area, since this relevant to the application and these do look like typical Beta distributions.

Answer (score 1):

This is a variant of an [$\text{AR}(1)$ process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model).

To be precise, let $(\epsilon_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with distribution $$\mathbb P[\epsilon_n=k]=p, \hspace{1cm}\mathbb P[\epsilon_n=0]=1-p.$$
Then our update rule can be rewritten as $X_{t+1}=(1-k)X_t+\epsilon_{t+1}$. Due to this recursion, we can express the solution as $$X_t=(1-k)^t\cdot X_0+\sum_{i=0}^{t-1} (1-k)^{t-i}\epsilon_{i}.$$

Note that regardless of the value/distribution of $X_0$, the first term vanishes as $t\to\infty$. However, as already pointed out by the other answer, it can become very tricky to compute the limiting distribution of the second term. I will only show that it exists, i.e. that the series converges almost-surely:

To do this, we may simply show that both the expected values and the variances of the sum converge. Convergence of the series then follows by [Kolmogorov's Three Series Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_three-series_theorem).

It is easily seen that $$\lim_t\mathbb E\bigg[\sum_{i=0}^{t-1}(1-k)^{t-i}\epsilon_i\bigg]=\lim_t\sum_{i=0}^{t-1}(1-k)^{t-i}pk<\infty$$ since $k\in (0,1)$ and similarly $$\lim_t\text{Var}\bigg(\sum_{i=0}^{t-1}(1-k)^{t-i}\epsilon_i\bigg)=\lim_t\sum_{i=0}^{t-1}(1-k)^{2(t-i)}\text{Var}(\epsilon_1)<\infty$$ again, since $k\in(0,1)$. In both computations we have simply used the convergence of the geometric series.

Comment: From the recursion displayed above it is clear that, because $\sum_{i=0}^{t-1}(1-k)^{t-i}\epsilon_i$ has the same distribution as $\sum_{j=1}^t(1-k)^j\epsilon_j$, the limit distribution of the Markov chain is the same as that of the random variable
$$
X_\infty:=\sum_{j=1}^\infty k(1-k)^j\xi_j,
$$
where $\xi_1,\xi_2,\ldots$ are iid Bernoulli r.v.s with mean $p$. Evidently $E[X_\infty] = (1-k)p$ and $\text{Var}[X_\infty] = {k^2(1-k)^2p(1-p)\over 1-(1-k)^2}$.

Comment: This is a helpful comment, and lead me to this which does actually reflect my simulations for $k=1/2$ and $p=1/2$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1268881/limit-distribution-of-infinite-sum-of-bernoulli-random-variables