# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{X_n}{2^n} \sim \mathcal{U}(0,1) $ for independent $X_n \sim Bern(1/2)$

Tags: probability-theory

> Let $(X_n)_{n \ge 1}$ be independent and $\textit{Bern}(0,1)$ distributed. Show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{X_n}{2^n}$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$.
>   Hint: Start with $\sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac{X_n}{2^n}$

I found a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1507188/probability-of-sum-n-1-infty-fracx-n2n-leq-p-for-bernoulli-sequenc), but I am unable to apply this on my problem. I don't have any other approaches, so I'm stuck.
Could anyone give me a hint? Thank you.

Edit:
This question was "put on hold" because "This question is missing context or other details". I am sorry. As you can see in the comments, I had a problem in understanding and didn't realize that the question I linked above basically is the same question.

Comment: This question you linked already has several answers plus hints in the comments. What part of the previous question were you having trouble with?

Comment: The question I linked shows that $P(S \le p) =f(p)=p$. Since I try to show $P(S = p)=1_{(0,1)}$, I tried to split the interval to $p<1/2$ and $p \ge 1/2$ aswell. So \\ 
@Jason $P(S=p)=1/2P(S=p|X_1=1)+1/2P(S=p|X_1=0)$ \\
I have $P(S=p|X_1=1)=0$, which is ok, but I also have $P(S=p|X_1=0)=1/2^m$ and this goes to $0$. The other two equations are $0$ aswell.

Comment: Hmm, you seem to be confused. You are trying to show $S$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$, which precisely means that $P(S\le p)=p$ for $p\in[0,1]$. In fact, you will have no luck with your method, since $P(S=p)=0$ for any $p$.

Comment: Yes, I am, sorry. Let me think about what you've wrote. $P(S \le p)=p 1_{(0,1)}$ describes the CDF, so by deriving, we get $P(S=p)=1_{(0,1)}$. Right?

Comment: Ahhh... if by $P(S=p)$ you mean the density function then yes, but this is poor notation. Why bother with the density at all? Once we have the CDF we have the distribution.

Comment: Yes, I meant the density function. But you are right, there is no reason to deal with the density. Thanky you very much for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we want to prove is that for every $x\in[0,1]$, $\displaystyle\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{X_n}{2^n}\leq x\right)=x$.

Assume that $\displaystyle\frac{i}{2^m}=0.y_1y_2\dots y_m$ for $(y_1,\dots,y_m)\in\{0,1\}^m$. Let us begin by computing the probability $\displaystyle \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{i}{2^m}\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{X_n}{n}< \frac{i+1}{2^m}\right)$. Notice that this probability is precisely equal to $\displaystyle\mathbb{P}\left(X_1=y_1,X_2=y_2,\dots,X_m=y_m\right)=\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^M\mathbb{P}\left(X_i=y_i\right)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{2^m}$.

Next, note that this implies:
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{X_n}{n}\leq \frac{i}{2^m}\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^i\left\{\frac{k-1}{2^m}\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{X_n}{n}< \frac{k}{2^m}\right\}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^i\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{k-1}{2^m}\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{X_n}{n}< \frac{k}{2^m}\right) = \frac{i}{2^m}.
$$

Hence, for any dyadic rational, the claim is proven. Now, using the fact that dyadic rationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, take a sequence of dyadic rationals $q_n$ such that $q_n \searrow x$. From the right continuity of the CDF, we have
$$
x = \lim_{n\to\infty} q_n = \lim_{q_n \searrow x}\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{X_n}{n}\leq q_n\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{X_n}{n} \leq x\right).
$$

**Remark** This is a fundamental step that allows us to construct an infinite sequence of independent $U[0,1]$ random variables, and therefore, allowing us to construct a sequence of independent random variables with prescribed distribution functions. In particular, the idea is to consider $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu) = ([0,1],\mathscr{B}_{[0,1]},\lambda)$, for any $\omega \in [0,1]$, expand $\omega$ in binary : $\omega = 0.\omega_1\omega_2\dots$, notice that $X_n = \omega_n$'s are independent $\rm{Ber}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ random variables. Taking a bijection $f : \mathbb{N}^2\to\mathbb{N}$, we construct:
$$
Y_n = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{X_{f(k,n)}}{2^k}.
$$
The argument above tells us that $\displaystyle \{Y_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of uniform (over $[0,1]$) random variables, and then applying Skorokhod representation, we construct a sequence of independent random variables with CDF's we wish.