# Existence of infinite independent event sequence with $0<P(A_i)<1$

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $(Ω,\mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space,and $\Omega$ is countable. Let $A_1,A_2, ...$ be **independent** events in $\mathcal{F}$. Can anybody provide an example where $0<P(A_i)<1$ for all $i\geq 1$ or prove it is impossible?

Related question:[An infinite sequence of independent events with constant probability is uncountable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2399478) and
[Existence of independent events](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3881567/) But we can't use second Borel-Cantelli lemma here because $\sum_i P(A_i)$ can be finite.

Comment: @lulu those aren't independent events though.

Comment: @whoisit  Ah, missed that condition.  Thanks.  Will delete.

Comment: @lulu let it be. That thought can occur to many people, even I thought that initially.

Comment: Renyi in his FOUNDATIONS OF PROBABILITY, 1970 Holden-Day, Chapter 3.3, p113 Example 3.3.3 constructs one.

Comment: @hyportnex Thanks for your help

Comment: if you do not have access to it I will put those pages up in imgur

Comment: Doesn't $A_i$=Head in the the i-th toss work? For the infinite coin toss model?

Comment: @hyportnex Thanks,I have downloaded the pdf of that book

Comment: @HackR $|\Omega|=2^{\mathbb{N}}$ and is uncountable?

Comment: Ah right, the countable condition. I forgot about that. My bad.